# Gulp or javascript remove html all unused inline style

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Purgecss can clear the css files connected in html to the unused css, but if all my styles are inline like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.unused-style { font-size: 14px; } // i wanna remove all unused inline style base on html file.

img { height: 80px; } // i wanna remove all unused inline style base on html file.
</style>
</head>
<body>Hello</body>
</html>
```

Is there any plugin / tips can do this?